# Chrome shortcut for hover : mostly for Grammarly

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, hover, keyboard-shortcuts

- To use [Grammarly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/grammarly-for-chrome/kbfnbcaeplbcioakkpcpgfkobkghlhen?hl=en) in Chrome, I use keyboard to move to the misspell, then I have to use the trackpad to enable the `Hover`, so Grammarly can make the suggestion.
- How can we use the keyboard (without mouse and trackpad) to do it (force hover)?

  - I would like to avoid trackpad as possible as I can.
  - My finger hurts after use trackpad.

Any approach that may work?
- maybe hidden shortcut from Grammerly, chrome extension, or Mac's shortcut or hidden settings.

Thanks.

Thanks :)

Comment: Sounds like something you should ask on Grammarly support site or forum. And anyway this doesn't seem to be a programming-related question so this is off-topic on SO.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I asked the question at https://support.grammarly.com/hc/en-us/requests/1735018. I will update this post if I found a solution. Also I think this question is more broad: may involve tricks about chrome or mac. I know stack exchange has a lot of sites, each focus on some domains, but as an engineer, I mostly(only) use SO.

Comment: @jeffery.yuan any updates? I get a 404 when i try to open https://support.grammarly.com/hc/en-us/requests/1735018